# Creating Boiler Plate Code using Macros

Tags: c++, macros, c-preprocessor

I have a bunch of classes such as the following,

```
class SomeClass : public Function{
public:

   ref call(ref args){
    // do & return stuff
   }

   int getType(){return TYPE;}
   ref toString(){ return "SomeClass";}
};
```

I got like 50 of these and the only thing that is different is the body of the call function. Is it possible to have a macro that will take a name and a body and replace "SomeClass" with name and insert body into call function?

Comment: you'll still end up having to write those 50 classes. Have a look at Boost.Preprocessor and the concept of Preprocessor List

Comment: @unapersson, can you tell me what it is? it sure isn't French.

Comment: @Joel Falcou, where I am doing this (on a microcontroller) I can't run Boost.

Comment: he, the Preprocessor library is just a bunch of macros in headers, so no worries on your MC stuff

Comment: You can use Boost.Preprocessor with practically any C or C++ compiler; it only utilizes the preprocessor so it should not affect performance at all.  It is very useful for code generation.

Comment: @Hamza I don't know - something you have made up yourself, I suppose, where you can declare  a function with a void return type and then return something.

Comment: @unapersson, that is called a typo, stackoverflow != reddit

Comment: @unapersson: If you have high enough rep (not sure the threshold on that permission), feel free to edit out the problem, and add a comment so it's obvious that it got changed.

Comment: @Hamza: Macros are widely considered to be tricky and bug prone.  One well known gotcha is the potential for multiple evaluation of the expression you pass in.  So if you're going to go with macros, read up on all the gotchas, and be really careful :)  You might want to first consider options using templates, if those options exist.

Comment: @Merlyn Templates and macros  have almost nothing in common.

Comment: @unapersson: They both can be used for code generation, and for many cases templates can be used instead of macros.  I admit it is hard to isolate variance when only one example is given (as in the question here).  But from what I can tell, this particular case creates similar classes varied on type, or single values, which are the simplest use case for templates.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sure.  Expanding the body of the `call` member function is a bit easier if you have a compiler that supports variadic macros.  While I've used Boost.Preprocessor's stringize macro, it is trivial to write your own.

```
#define DEFINE_CLASS(name, parenthesized_call_body)                 \
    class name : public Function {                                  \
        ref call (ref args) {                                       \
            DEFINE_CLASS_CALL_BODY parenthesized_call_body          \
        }                                                           \
        int getType() { return TYPE; }                              \
        const char* toString() { return BOOST_PP_STRINGIZE(name); } \
    };

#define DEFINE_CLASS_CALL_BODY(...) __VA_ARGS__
```

Used as:

```
DEFINE_CLASS(SomeClass, (return ref()))
```

The `call` body needs to be parenthesized so that any commas present in the body are not treated as macro argument separators.  Alternatively, you could just declare the `call` function in the class definition and then define that function separately.

Comment: Just say no to preprocessor abuse.

Comment: @Chris:  Using the preprocessor for code generation is not preprocessor abuse.  (I don't know that I'd use a macro for the OP's specific use case, but I regularly use macros for defining enumerations and exception classes where I would otherwise have to write repetitive, unmaintainable code.)

Comment: Hey I didn't downvote you or anything, it's a good answer, but in general I've found that this kind of preprocessor magic leads to nightmares for the maintainers down the line.

Comment: using boost.preprocessor FILE_ITERATE is actually nicer as you have your code not embedded in a macro but as a part of a file. Error goes where they should when reported by the compiler and you keep syntax hightlighting

Comment: @Chris tend to disagree. This is very clean and easily maintainable macros. Defining something in one place in such structured manner makes maintenance easy.

Comment: Well then it's fisticuffs! Have at you, sir!

Comment: @James McNellis, Great works like a charm one other question is it possible to use {} instead of (), can I wrap the body in a pair of {}?

Comment: No, the preprocessor only matches parentheses.

Answer (score 2):

To avoid wrapping the body of the function in a macro invocation, you can split the class-defining macro into prefix and suffix:

```
#define DEFINE_FUNCTION_CLASS_BEGIN(name) \
    class name : public Function { \
    public: \
        ref call(ref args) {

#define DEFINE_FUNCTION_CLASS_END \
        } \
        int getType() { return TYPE; } \
        void toString() { return #name; } \
    };
```

Invoke with:

```
DEFINE_FUNCTION_CLASS_BEGIN(SomeClass)

// Stuff.

DEFINE_FUNCTION_CLASS_END
```

Alternatively, use a template:

```
template<int Type>
class SomeClass : public Function {
public:
    int getType() { return Type; }
    ref call(ref args) {}
    std::string toString() {}
};
```

And specialise it:

```
template<>
ref SomeClass<TYPE>::call(ref args) {
    // Stuff.
};

template<>
std::string SomeClass<FOO>::toString() {
    return "FOO";
};
```

Answer (score 0):

You've used a mass `getType()` and `toString()` functions? This isn't Java or C#, and looking at your code, I think that you need some additional C++ tuition- another example is that you returned "SomeClass" from a function that *returns void*.

However, what you want can be done with a pretty simple template.

```
template<typename T> class SomeClass : public Function {
    T t;
public:
    SomeClass(const T& ref)
        : t(ref) {}
    ret call(args) {
        return t(args);
    }
    int getType() { return TYPE; }
    std::string toString() { return "someClass"; } 
};

ret func(argtypes) { ... }
SomeClass<ret(*)(argtypes)> instance(func);
struct lols {
    // .. Whatever you want in here
    ret operator()(args) { ... };
}
SomeClass<lols> anotherinstance(lols()); // or constructor arguments if needed
```

Comment: templates won't do, I am trying to insert the function body.

Comment: @Hamza: Check my edit. There is no need to use a macro in this scenario.

Comment: returning void, it is a typo, I am using my own object system, thats why getType and toString is there, I just got tired of writing a half page of explanation as to why I am reinventing the wheel every time I ask a question  plz see my earlier questions as to why.